# how to do the ibmmq replication in docker swarm or kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ibm-mq, message-queue, ibm-integration-bus

I am running the mq container on top of docker followed by the [link](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-docker)  and my container status is up. but unable to get the web-UI. It shows the logs as

`2018-09-17T20:19:59.364Z AMQ9207E: The data received from host '10.10.10.10' on channel '????' is not valid.
2018-09-17T20:19:59.364Z AMQ9492E: The TCP/IP responder program encountered an error.`

Could anybody suggest me how to run the IIB/MQ Cluster using Docker and Kubernetes inorder to achieve the auto Scaling and High Availability?

Comment: How are you running it exactly? What commands are you using to start it? Are you using Kubernetes?

Comment: thank you Rico for responding. `docker run --name myNode -e LICENSE=accept -e NODENAME=MYNODE -e SERVERNAME=MYSERVER -e MQ_QMGR_NAME=QM1 -v qm2data:/mnt/mqm -P ibmcom/mq`.currently i am running on docker. i am not able the get web-ui. it shows as `didn’t send any data`

Comment: Are you referring to MQ's WebUI or some other UI?

Comment: i am referring MQ's WebUI.

Comment: you have to configure and start the webgui. It's not running by default. You find all information on how to do that in IBM's knowledge center.